# Closing Open Sides of a Mesh with Python

Tags: mesh, scripting

I have hundreds of rectangular mesh. All of them are cut from a rectangular box shape object (actually cube with extended x and y axes). All of the new objects has multiple open sides as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am having issues with these open sides as Union operator does not work perfectly with open meshes. Is there any way of closing the open sides?

Currently I am using this following scripts to close the opening. However, it takes all the vertices then try to fill with respect to all of them. Thus, the opening are not closing as expected.

```
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

bm = bmesh.new()
# import from obj file here, only imported objects will be 
# in context.selected_objects after import.    
for o in context.selected_objects:
    # test here to continue if not mesh, can obj import other???
    # load bmesh
    bm.from_mesh(o.data)
    # find boundaries
    bound_edges = set(e for e in bm.edges if e.is_boundary)
    # used sets, may not be required.
    zero_edges = set(e for e in bound_edges if all(abs(v.co.x) < 0.001 for v in e.verts))
    right_edges = bound_edges - zero_edges
    # use bmesh "F" tool
    result = bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=list(bound_edges))
    # poke the resulting faces to make triangular fan.
    bmesh.ops.poke(bm, faces=result["faces"])
    bm.to_mesh(o.data)
    o.data.update() # mainly only need for UI really
    bm.clear()
bm.free()
```

Is there any way of closing the opening as I am expecting (as shown in the image which was achived by manually selecting the vertices and pressing "F") ?

[image]

Comment: How do you define the opening edge? The figures you showed is a little bit unclear what should be closed

Comment: First though, using something similar to the ears clipping method used to triangulate meshes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation#Ear_clipping_method (here of course, considering boundaries only)